# MOV instruction - how it works

Tags: x86, mov

I have the following `MOV` instruction:

```
mov [SI], DX

SI = 3333h
DX = A3A3h
IP = 104h
```

Everything is clear, the A3A3h value is saved under the 3333h adress.

However I found some strange explanation of this specific `mov` instruction:

```
[30030 + 3333]tj[33363] = A3A3
```

Ignoring the strange tj thing - what is the 30030 part here, and where did it came from?

Comment: You have to ask whoever wrote the strange explanation.

Comment: I thought maybe that's some common convention...thanks.

Comment: Even if were some common convention, the person who wrote the strange explanation should have explained it. As written here, the remark is out of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the "tj" is about but here's an explanation of the move:

```
MOV [SI],DX
```

This moves the contents of `DX` into the memory location whose address is in `SI` off of the `DS` (data segment) register. So the:

```
[30030 + 3333]tj[33363] = A3A3
```

I believe is giving an example but, unfortunately, you're not showing what any of the segment registers are set to, particularly `DS`. So my guess is the `DS` is `3003`. So the address would be calculated as `(DS << 4) + SI`, or `30030 + 3333`. After the "tj" they just added this up to give a final address of `33363`.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant! But the address here seems to be absolute...Why do I need to use segment register then?

Comment: @user2489034 The 8086 architecture is a segmented, 20-bit address architecture as Mike W pointed out. If you were to implement a 16-bit 8086 application, you would just set `DS` to `0` but it would have to be set. The `mov [si], dx` gives you relative addressing in the sense of it's indirect off of `si`. Ultimately, everything has to resolve to an absolute address, however.

Answer (score 1):

My X86 knowledge is somewhat rusty but if I remember it correctly the 30030 part is most likely coming from the data segment register (DS) which is 3003 in this case.
The final address is computed as Segment * 16 + index register in this case DS and SI.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember rightly, and its a *very* long time ago, 8086 addressing was made up of two parts - a 16bit address and another 16-bit address offset by 4 bits to give a page address. These two parts were combined to give a 20-bit address into physical memory. The `8086` is long dead, but its instruction set lives on for compatibility.